# on Vertica Drag Update does not work as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

i have written the following code which make the Container swiping left when user want to.
i used here  `GestureDetector`  `onPanUpdate` for handling the swipe left
also i used `onPanEnd` to return the container to it's default location with reset my global `double swipH varible to` 0` and the same with vertical

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

double swipH = 0 ;
double swipV = 0 ;
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {

 bool  isV = true ;
 bool isH = true ;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body:   Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [

          GestureDetector(




              onLongPress: (){
                debugPrint('vvvvvvvvv');
              },




                onPanUpdate:(noti){

                  if(noti.delta.dy < 0&&isV){
                    isH = false;
                    swipV += noti.delta.dy;
                    setState(() {});
                  }

                  if(noti.delta.dx < 0&&isH){
                    isV = false;
                    debugPrint('Started');
                    swipH += noti.delta.dx;
                    setState(() {});
                  }
                },

            onPanEnd:(noti){
                isV = true ;
               isH = true ;
              swipH=0;
              swipV = 0 ;
              setState(() {});
            },


              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(swipH, swipV),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),

            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

EDIT
sorry i forget to include the following

```
 onLongPress: (){
 debugPrint('onLongPress');
  },
```

[image]

any good idea instead most welcome

everything work fine without to use `onLongPress`.. but i need this method with the same logic in example

Comment: Can you provide a gif or image about your desire output? I am not getting `only one side in every single swipe`

Comment: done , please take a look

Comment: i edit the code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use another `bool?` to track the initial movement direction and checking on drag.

```dart
double swipH = 0;
double swipV = 0;

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  bool? _isDx;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (noti) {
                if (noti.delta.dy < 0 && _isDx != false) {
                  swipV += noti.delta.dy;
                  _isDx = true;
                }

                if (noti.delta.dx < 0 && _isDx != true) {
                  swipH += noti.delta.dx;
                  _isDx = false;
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
              onPanEnd: (noti) {
                debugPrint('end');
                swipH = 0;
                swipV = 0;
                _isDx = null;
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(swipH, swipV),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you sure you see the full question Edit ?

Comment: well I saw last one `i want only one side in every single swipe`  and proceed to solve by seeing image, can you provide an gif, or what issue are you facing from this post

Comment: no doubt that  you solved the problem .. but when i use on Long press every logic in my example and your example not work as expected .. that's was my real issue

Comment: You can try calling `onLongPressMoveUpdate`

Comment: i solved it with Listener Widget .. it already suit with GtDetctor